# Disconnected my hot water supply line for the kitchen sink by accident, easy fix or call a plumber?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pipe-fitting, old-pipes

Sorry for the poor image quality. I was installing a water shut off valve for my kitchen sink, and I jostled my hot water line too much while doing the two wrench thing. Apparently pulled the pipe clean off. I didn't realize until I tested my work by turning the water on and heard water flowing in my crawlspace.

Is this an issue of simply reseating the pipe, or do I need to call a plumber? If this is DIY-able I'm comfortable attempting myself but thought I'd ask some more experienced folks instead of just guessing. If it's a reseating issue, do I need any additional supplies (i.e. something to increase the pipe's sturdiness). I'm assuming it was already loose, but I'm not sure if that's just how these connections work.

[image]

Comment: It can be done by someone with the appropriate skill set. In your case, no offense,  I suggest a plumber.

Comment: " I was installing a water shut off valve for my kitchen sink" What kind? copper? CPVC?

Comment: That's a crap location to have to work, and why it failed. Picture of before it comes through there? Because you could cut it somewhere easier to work, put a threaded fitting for screwing a shut-off valve on it, then just use a 15' supply line. Pressure will suffer a little and you'll have to go down there to turn it off... but this will be repair *#3* on that line, minimum (was galvanized; became PVC... still sucks).

Answer (score 2):

That looks like CPVC that can be glued.  I do not see where the disconnected pipe should be re-attached.

However if both ends ( male and female) are cleaned and dry. Apply the appropriate [primer and glue](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Oatey-Handypack-4-fl-oz-CPVC-Cement/4751293?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_142_Pipe-Fittings-_-4751293-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjw5remBhBiEiwAxL2M96V1aAGsdBwaXNAphpYRtRvyq1tjtpYYkSFsnGDycWrSQEzU7_hpRhoCqVMQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)  to both pipe and fitting and push together with as much force as you can. Hold for 30 seconds and wipe off any extra glue. Wait about an hour, (or what is recommended on the glue bottle). Then turn the water back on and check for leaks.